# React Native Android App run on emulator doesn't connect to metro bundler when installed using android-studio

Tags: react-native, android-studio, metro-bundler

My React-Native(0.68.1) project runs properly on my emulator when using npx react-native run-android command and everything works fine with the metro bundler instance created by this command.

Only when I run project from android studio (2021.3.1 Patch 1) , app is build successfully and installed on emulator, but cannot connect to metro bundler (which I separately run using npx react-native start command).

I wanted to try and update the debug server & port as mentioned in other similar questions , but I cannot access the debug app menu even after dismissing the error (menu doesn't show when ipress the shortcut)

Issue also occurs on build installed on emulator via npx react-native run-android when I close the app and metro bundler created by the command and start a separate metro bundler. In this case but I am able to enter settings menu and enter "debug server and port " to 10.0.2.2:8081 and app connects to metro.

I am using mac mini m1.

Comment: as far as i know `npx react-native start` only gets metro started. for also start android emulator - you need to use `npx react-native run-android`

Comment: @happyZZR1400 debug build app already built and installed to emulator from android studio. I start metro separately from terminal afterwards. but the installed app refuses to connect to the metro bundler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this issue

first of all, start your emulator and run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` this command on the terminal and then run `npx react-native start` and then run your project in the android studio and it will automatically link your app to that bundle

Comment: Thank you it's working. Could you please tell me why "npx react-native run-android" command does not require this port forwarding for emulators? Also why isn't this required in windows ??